# why does not header informaion show in browser

Tags: php

a simple php file contains simple php code with header information, page display correctly but header informaion does not show correctly, what is it reason, my hosting on hostgator with apche mysql php

```
?php 
// PHP program to describes header function 
  
// Set a past date 
header("Expires: Sun, 25 Jul 1997 06:02:34 GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
?> 
  
<html> 
    <body> 
        <p>Hello World!</p> 
      
        <!-- PHP program to display 
        header list --> 
        <?php 
            print_r(headers_list()); 
        ?> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

result shown

Hello World!
Array ( [0] => Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 )

Comment: The header information is part of the message that tells the browser about the message content. It's not intended for display

Answer (score 0):

Because its Cache

### What is Cache?

Cache-Control is an HTTP cache header, Which simply Makes your website Faster, Also it can help your website when using Private Info!!!

### How to see if my website is caching?

Inspect Elements -> Network -> click on the image / file -> Responses Header -> cache-control

### Settings Up cache

For Php

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');
?>
```

For Apache

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
</filesMatch>
```

For nginx

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 2d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
}
```

Comment: One particular header is about cache. There are many others. The OP didn't ask how to set them in the web server: they asked why they're not displayed.